# malloc overwrites argument passed by value

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, undefined-behavior

I want to allocate memory for a 2D array such that the arrays have increasing incremental memory. This means `array[0]` can hold 1 `uint32_t`, array[1] can hold 2 `uint32_t`, etc. Think of it as a triangle.

I have a function that takes in as a parameter `rows` the maximum number of variables the final array can hold. So we have `rows` number of arrays (`array[0]` to `array[rows-1]`), holding a number of variables of 1 to `rows`.

After initialising and allocating memory for the main array, we can use a `for` loop to initialise then allocate for each sub-array incrementally. We have to do this in two seperate expressions since the incrementer `i` is inheritally variable.

We should have something like this (I know I didn't `free` memory but that's not the issue):

```
#define ROWS 15

int main()
{
    uint32_t** array = triangle2array(FILEPATH, ROWS, DIGITS);
    ...
}

uint32_t** triangle2array(const char* filepath, uint8_t rows, uint8_t digits)
{
    uint32_t** row = (uint32_t**) malloc(rows*sizeof(uint32_t*));
    if (row == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "row memory is not allocated\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        // Initialise memory for sub-array, i.e. arrays that hold the numbers on a specific row
        uint32_t* row[i];
        row[i] = (uint32_t*) malloc((i+1)*sizeof(uint32_t));
        if (row[i] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "row[%zi] memory is not allocated\n", i);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        assert(rows == ROWS);
    }
    return row;
}
```

It doesn't work. According to a debugger, the argument `rows` is addressed to `0x00007FFFFFFFDFA4` while `row[0]` is addressed to `0x00007FFFFFFFDFA0`. Essentially, `row[0]` is addressed 4 bytes before `rows` and when `malloc` is allocated, the memory is paved onto `rows` giving `rows` a random value.

What's weird is that if I make a mirror function and do essentially the same thing, it works perfectly fine:

```
#define MACRO 15

void example(uint8_t);

int main(void)
{
    example(MACRO);
    return 0;    
}

void example(uint8_t macro)
{
    uint32_t** row = malloc(macro*sizeof(uint32_t*));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < macro; i++) {
        uint32_t* row[i];
        row[i] = malloc((i+1)*sizeof(uint32_t));
    }
    assert(macro == MACRO);
    free(row);
}
```

I honestly don't know how to approach this issue.

Comment: You are shadowing the `row` variable by declaring one more `row` inside `for` loop.

Comment: @kiranBiradar How do you mean? `rows` is a number and `row` is a memory address.

Comment: `uint32_t** row = malloc(macro*sizeof(uint32_t*));` and `uint32_t* row[i];` are two different variables with the same name.

Comment: Time to enable those compiler warnings... `-Wshadow` etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        // Initialise memory for sub-array, i.e. arrays that hold the numbers on a specific row
        uint32_t* row[i];
        row[i] = (uint32_t*) malloc((i+1)*sizeof(uint32_t));
        if (row[i] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "row[%zi] memory is not allocated\n", i);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        assert(rows == ROWS);
    }
```

Your problem is the line `uint32_t* row[i];`. I don't know what you intended it to do, but what it actually does is declare a new array named `row` of size `i`, local to the body of the `for` loop. In other words, the following assignment

```
row[i] = (uint32_t*) malloc((i+1)*sizeof(uint32_t));
```

does not assign to the dynamic array `row` you `malloc`ed earlier, but out of bounds of this nested array `row`. Remove the spurious declaration `uint32_t* row[i];` and your code should work.